# Is it possible to have multiple keys in oiosaml keystore?

Tags: encryption, saml, saml-2.0, signing, opensaml

I am working on OIOSAML with ADFS 2.0. I need the IdP response to be signed as well as encrypted. Below is my understanding on how signing and encryption of SAML request and response works:

1. SP signs the request using its own certificate key (Key-1)
2. IdP verifies the request using SP's public key (Key-1)
3. IdP signs the response using its own certificate key (Key-2)
4. IdP encrypts the response assertion using certificate key provided by SP (Key-3)
5. SP verifies response using IdP's public key (Key-2)
6. SP decrypts the response assertion using its own private key (Key-3)

If I keep Key-1 and Key-3 same, everything works. As my keystore in OIOSAML has only one key.

But now I want to use separate keys for request signing and response encryption. It fails here.

1. Does OIOSAML support multiple keys in keystore?
2. If yes then how does it distinguish between signing and encryption keys?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available from [OIOSAML release 3](https://www.digitaliser.dk/resource/4390927).